# logback.xml not logging to Console or File - Getting error "Element type "configuration" must be declared."

Tags: java, spring, logback

I have followed multiple links on SO and other sources on the internet and modified my logback.xml but it is still not working. Please help.

I have a web application in Maven using Java 1.7 and Spring 4.3.13.RELEASE.

logback.xml under src/main/resources

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>
<configuration>
    <property name="log.folder" value="/logs" />
    <property name="log.activity.fileName" value="myapp.log" />
    <property name="log.file.maxsize" value="90MB" />

    <appender name="CONSOLELOGGER" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.err"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" /> 
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="MYLOGGER" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${log.folder}/${log.activity.fileName}</File>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %-5p [%c] %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/${log.activity.fileName}.%d{YYYY-MM-dd}-%i</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 100MB -->
                <maxFileSize>${log.file.maxsize}</maxFileSize>
                <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
                <!-- <maxHistory>30</maxHistory> -->
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <param name="locationInfo" value="true" />
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.mypackage" level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="MYLOGGER"/>
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLELOGGER" />
        <appender-ref ref="MYLOGGER" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

servlet.xml contains

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:logback.xml" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

Pom has

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Complete error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element type "configuration" must be declared.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: why do you need `<!DOCTYPE configuration>`? have you tried to remove it?

Comment: yes without <!DOCTYPE configuration> I get the error 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null".

Comment: your log-back appender config doesn't seem correct as you are using appender class from log4j. you can refer this https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html

Comment: @lucid I updated with logback classes but got the error "Element type "configuration" must be declared."
I updated the log4j classes to ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender and  ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender.